# how to zoom div content in Jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell how how to zoom div content in jQuery? I am able to zoom but problem is that zoom is going in height not on width. Please check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eT4Tq/1/)

```
$('#zoomin').click(
    function() {
        alert("--")
        $("#divelement").animate({ 'zoom': 1.2 }, 400);
    });

    $('#zoomout').click(
    function() {
        alert("-zoomout-")
        $("#divelement").animate({ 'zoom': 1 }, 400);
    });
```

Comment: zoom is not a standard CSS property. Depending on what your purposes are, you might want to look at changing the font size or using CSS transforms.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set a width for the target

```
.divClass{

    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    border:1px solid red
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eT4Tq/2/)

Comment: How can the  _content_  of the `div` also be included in the 'popup'?

Answer (score 0):

You set width to a percent value. You must change it to px or cm.

Use

```
.divClass{
    width: 100px; /* Fixed value */
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red
}
```